# Maximum HDD size supported by drives connected via PCI Express

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pci-express

is the maximum supported HDD size of drives that are connected via PCI Express expansion cards limited by the motherboard of the PC or by the PCI Express card/driver?

Why do I want to know that? I have a good old but silent and energy efficient PC system that only supports 3 TB HDDs. I was wondering if there is a chance to circumvent this limitation by an expansion card.

Looking at some PCI Express card datasheets I cannot find an answer. I otherwise might ask the vendors directly but maybe here is a good place for others that have the same question :)

Comment: What model is your PC, and why do you think it's limited to 3TB?

Comment: Wow, that's a fast reply :) It is this one here: https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X10SBA-L There it is stated that it only supports 3TB. And I can prove that a 10 TB drive is not recognized at OS level (linux does not show any /dev/sdx entry for a drive above 3 TB).

Comment: Does the system's firmware have any SATA-related settings (like the usual "IDE vs AHCI" mode switch)? 3TB is a very odd number to stop at, even more so for SATA/AHCI.

Comment: Yes there is the IDE vs. AHCI switch.

Comment: Is it set to AHCI? Are there any other SATA-related settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the disk isn't recognized by Linux, then the limit is most likely in the motherboard's built-in SATA controller (possibly an artificial limit, as 3TB is a somewhat odd boundary).

It might be *related to* the system's firmware (BIOS), as the firmware has an opportunity to configure the motherboard's built-in SATA controller in a specific way before booting the OS (e.g. it's common for the firmware to switch the controller into "IDE emulation" mode if the OS doesn't support AHCI) – though with any modern OS, once the OS is booted it talks directly to the controller (not through the BIOS anymore) and isn't subject to the "old" BIOS-era limits, but the controller configuration that the BIOS set will still be in effect.

If you're buying e.g. an external SATA or SCSI/SAS controller/HBA card, then the limit will likely be decided entirely by the card's capabilities, as the system firmware won't be able to configure external controllers (and won't be programmed to do so anyway).

PCI Express has no general disk size limit because PCI Express doesn't deal with *disks* – it's a generic bus that doesn't particularly care what devices are attached to it, any more than an Ethernet port doesn't care about HTTP vs FTP.

Answer (score 2):

The 3TB limitation is listed under the BIOS section, which probably
means that the BIOS and Windows boot files must be stored in the
first 3TB of the disk.
In other words, this is a limitation of the BIOS software.

Windows does not use the BIOS for disk access after it boots, so this
limitation probably does not apply for Windows itself.

However, I suggest you buy your larger-than-3TB disk from a vendor with
a good return policy, just in case.